# Google Tracking not sending hits

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

Good day all,

Im following some training on Udacity where they showing us how to use google analytics for tracking my app usage.

I followed the training to the T which meant creating a "MyApplication" class and instantiating it on start up.

Code in MyApplication.java extends Application

```
    public Tracker mTracker;

public void startTracking() {

    if (mTracker == null) {

        GoogleAnalytics ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mTracker = ga.newTracker(R.xml.track_app);
        ga.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
        ga.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        System.out.println("Tracking - Tracking has started a new object");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Tracking - Tracking has already been started");

    }
}

public Tracker getTracker() {

    startTracking();
    return mTracker;

}
```

and then call the StartTracking() in the onCreate method on the class that is launched when the app is started. Problem im having is for some stupid reason probably its not send the hits to GAnalytics!

I've also create the Tracking_app.xml file which contains my GA Tracking Code and the screen names as well as set the permissions in the Android Manifest and set the android:name=".MyApplication" in the manifest.

I'm so lost as to what i need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a file call `app_tracker.xml`

It is suppose to look as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="myapplication.MainActivity">
        MainActivity
    </screenName>
    <screenName name="myapplication.SplashScreen">
        SplashScreen
    </screenName>
    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-(this is private :p)</string>
</resources>
```

and another one called  `analytics_global_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_appName">Your app name here</string>
    <string name="ga_appVersion">app version here</string>
    <!--Remember to disable verobse log level for production -->
    <string name="ga_logLevel">Verbose</string>
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1000</integer>
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Take care that your `ga_trackingId` is valid.